# How to use PowerShell to log SCCM Apps not installed

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script to read from a list of computers to scan for Apps not installed from the Software Center. I have the following, but nothing is getting written to the CSV file. I also need to know if a system is offline as well. Can someone assist if at all possible?

```
$compList = "\\xxx\C$\VIPER\comps1.txt"
$scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
foreach ($server in (Get-Content $compList)) {
Try { 
$info = get-wmiobject -ComputerName $server -query `
"SELECT * FROM CCM_Application" -namespace "ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK" | `
Where-Object {$_.InstallState -eq 'NotInstalled'} | `
Select @{Label='ComputerName';Expression={$server}},Name,Id,SoftwareVersion
}
Catch {
$info = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    ComputerName=$server
    Name="System Offline"
    Id="System Offline"
    SoftwareVersion="System Offline"
    }
    }
}
$info | Export-CSV \\xxx\C$\VIPER\scans\Apps_Missing.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Try running the WMI query without filtering. Does that work? If it does, does filtering with where-object still return values? Add Select-Object, how's the output now?

Comment: You keep overwriting the value of `$info` every time the loop runs

Comment: Why don't you just use the built in SCCM reporting?

Comment: Either way, you're are you creating a PSObject everytime if fails? Also, why are you using a try/catch? `Get-WmiObject` will not output an error if it's unable to find anything. You're better off just running the query with no try/catch and testing your condition later.

Comment: Oh, and also, don't use `$info` for both,  your success and fail scenario....

Comment: So can someone possibly show the correct way if at all possible? - Thanks!!!